# Changing study fields

Tags: biology

After reading countless posts about this topic, I still can't find my answer. I'm a little lost on the future study plan...

I am currently studying Advertising and PR but do not have an amazing interest in it. I will finish my undergrad next year and looking for postgrad opportunities. However, I was wondering how realistic it is to be looking at postgrad courses in animal science, biology, marine biology and so on...

I know it is 'easy' to switch from science to social but is it possible to do the switch the other way around?

Thanks!

Comment: What coursework or experience do you have in the fields that you want to go to grad school for?

Comment: As I have said on many questions of this type: look carefully at the target program of studies, analyze the course sequence, prerequisites, course descriptions.  See what additional courses you would need.  What you're proposing can be done but requires careful preparation. // If you have any specific questions about a particular degree program, please provide a link to the program description and articulate your question clearly.

Comment: What country are you in, and what have you studied outside of your main subject during your undergrad?  The answer can be quite different in different educational systems.

Comment: I am currently studying in Spain, I have been here for most of my academic life but really would like a change of pace and study elsewhere... My main courses here are marketing, advertising and public relations but it doesn't seem to be something I am passionate about. I don't plan to go full on scientist and study chemistry or physics alone. More like and enviromental study, animal science or related to marine biology. Thanks for the answers!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that you can make such a radical change without having to take a number of additional make-up courses at the undergraduate level, and your current training does not appear to have much overlap with your future plans.